# Can potentials be used to transmit energy and information?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, potential, aharonov-bohm

The famous Aharonov-Bohm effect displays  the potential of the physical implications of different potential gauges in em theory.

I saw very few experimental and theoretical investigations into this phenomenon that has been confirmed experimentally and has a solid theoretical backing.

Could this be exploited to transmit signals or energy instead of using field radiation which is limited in scope when it comes to energy transmission, and limited by the speed of induction c when it comes to signal transmission, while pure pure em potentials don't share these limitations at least in theory.

Classically this is prohibited by Maxwell theory, but that is just an approximation of a deeper reality.

Comment: Where did you see that *"limited by [...] c [...] while pure EM potentials don't share these limitations at least in theory"*? Also, The Aharonov-Bohm effect arises due to a Wilson loop, which involves the Faraday tensor by Stokes' theorem, thus I don't know what your very first sentence is supposed to mean...

Comment: In order to change to change the Aharonov-Bohm phase (ie to transmit information in this way), you would need to change the current passing through a solenoid. How are you going to send a signal to tell the current in the solenoid to change, *without* using electromagnetic radiation?

Comment: It means that it was usually taken that potentials are just math tools, but they are actually known now to be more fundamental than fields